# Search a file and migrate search term is in to a new file

Tags: php, string, string-search

This code enables to create a new .txt file, if the file doesn't exist yet, it will create the file.

```
<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

And this code here identifies each line of string into a token.

```
<?php
$string = "This is\tan example\nstring";
/* Use tab and newline as tokenizing characters as well  */
$tok = strtok($string, " \n\t");

while ($tok !== false) {
    echo "Word=$tok<br />";
    $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
}
?>
```

The people.txt looks like this

```
John Smith
John Meyer
John Chase 
John Smith    //i want to transfer this set of string into a new file
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: I want to transfer a set of string into a different file, by identify first the first and last string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$searchTerm = 'John Smith';
$file = 'people.txt';
$fileFound = 'peopleFound.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
if (strpos($searchTerm, $current) !== false) {
    file_put_contents($fileFound, $searchTerm."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: I wanna add some questions, what if john smith will be set as identifier so that it could transfer the set of texts between the *john smith* string?

Comment: Between "John Smith" and what?

Answer (score 0):

```
$fp=fopen('people.txt','a+');
fputs($fp,"John Smith\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```

open and append the file, don't read it all in and append to the back and write it all back out. when the file gets past a certain size that will be real inefficient. I'm not sure how it is you're trying to tokenize it. seems to me you could just do a `$names=file('people.txt');` and have them in an array immediately...